# "Корзина" SQLite или как правильно

Tags: android, sqlite

У меня на главном экране есть список (из БД), можно добавлять и удалять пункты. Я создать еще один список (таблица "Корзина"), чтобы удаленные пункты перемещались туда, а оттуда если пользователь пожелает, восстановит, если пожелает удалить безвозвратно. Вопрос, если на слушатель удаления из главного списка я добавлю метод, перемещающий текущий пункт с его содержимым в таблицу корзины, а с текущего списка удалю, будет ли это правильным подходом?

Comment: Нет, помечайте записи, заведите поле с пометкой в корзине или "нормальные" то что вы хотите сделать - повысит фрагметарность базы

Comment: В принципе исчерпывающе, можете вывести в ответ, отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подход не является единственно верным. при таком подходе повышается фрагментарность базы.
В вашей задаче лучшем будет завести "поле" в базе, которым записи перемещенные в корзину будут помечаться, при полном удалении - запись удаляется, при восстановлении - снимается пометка о нахождении в корзине.